# Ordernar Array Agrupado Lodash vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un array que he creado agrupando otro array por medio de una propiedad en donde cada item es otro array agrupados por una propiedad he creado esta estructura usando lodash vue, pero necesito ordenar el array resultante a través del length del array que esta agrupado.

```
let arr = [
{'alerts': [1,2],'area': '51'},
{'alerts': [1,2,3,4],'area': '52'},
{'alerts': [1,2,3],'area': '53'}
```

];

Como pueden observar dentro del array tengo otro array(alerts) que estan agrupados por la propiedad area entonces necesito que este me los devuelva ordenados descendente por el array alerts que tenga mas items.
Lo correcto seria de la siguiente manera.

Area "51" por que tiene 4 items
Area "53" tiene 3 items
ETC

El codigo que utilize para agrupar la data es el siguiente

```
            this.dataGroup = _(this.$store.state.Alert)
            .groupBy('area')
            .map(function (items, area) {
                return {
                    area: area,
                    alerts: items
                    
                };
            }).value();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con lodash [_.sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy), sólo que le añades `lenght` para que en vez de ordenarlo por el valor de la propiedad `alerts`, lo ordene por la cantidad de elementos que contiene el array en esa propiedad:

```js
let arr = [
  {'alerts': [1,2],'area': '51'},
  {'alerts': [1,2,3,4],'area': '52'},
  {'alerts': [1,2,3],'area': '53'}
];


deMenorAMayor = _.sortBy(arr, function(item) {
   return item['alerts'].length;
});

deMayorAMenor = _.sortBy(arr, function(item) {
   return - item['alerts'].length;
});


console.log(deMenorAMayor);
console.log(deMayorAMenor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```